# Merging different types of charts in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I am merging an XY Scatter Plot with a time series chart on Excel 2010. However, the XY Scatter Plot has multiple variables on the same date, thereby making the merge problematic.

The data for the XY Scatter Plot looks something like this...

```
Date    Value
1/1/01  50
1/1/01  75
1/2/01  100
1/3/01  125
```

But the data for the Time Series assigns one value per date...

```
Date    Value
1/1/01  60
1/2/01  85
1/3/01  110
```

Has anybody encountered this problem before? And what would be the workaround?

Comment: Define "problematic".

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to *make it work*. :)

Insert a dummy point to align with the number of values in the scatter such that it is the average of the surrounding points. Do this for both the category and value (A8: `=AVERAGE(A7,A9)` and B8: `=AVERAGE(B7,B9)`). Then manipulate the data point of the time series (if you have any) to be none.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The time series I'm working with are daily stock price data trailing 10 years. For analytical purposes, I don't think I could insert dummy points as described (and for thousands of row at that). The workaround I found was to insert a secondary x-axis for the scatter plot and recalibrate so that both x-axis' match the beginning and end dates.